# diff to another branch and show lines changed and file operations for each file

Tags: git

The bitbucket web UI has a nifty compare feature where I can diff to another branch and see files changed. But it ALSO show me more context about those changes:

[image]

Im not interested in a git output parsing bash script I could just write myself. 
I want to know if this is possible with a regular git command.

`git diff otherbranch --name-only` shows me files that changed, is there a switch/option to add lines changed and if the file was delete/added/modified etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two

```
git diff --name-status otherbranch
git diff --stat otherbranch
```

Comment: thats good enough for me, be cool if it squeezed both onto the same line though